# Running Total of Open Accounts SQL Server 2008 by Month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have found loads of articles similar to what I’m attempting to do but just cannot seem to replicate it to work.
I have a transactions table that is as below :

```
AccountNo   Status  DateComplete    DateDue    State
1147331     OPEN    18/02/2011      10/03/2011  R
1146787     OPEN    07/04/2011      05/04/2011  R
16511       OPEN    29/09/2003      29/09/2003  R
22571       OPEN    15/10/2003      15/10/2003  R
2852403     OPEN    10/11/2014      10/11/2014  R
2851890     OPEN    17/11/2014      17/11/2014  R
1147331     CLOSED  24/06/2011      27/06/2011  R
1146787     CLOSED  14/06/2011      14/06/2011  R
2852403     CLOSED  11/08/2015      11/08/2015  F
2851890     CLOSED  18/08/2015      18/08/2015  F
```

I don’t have access to change any of the data so have to work with what I have. The State column shows if a status is completed or pending. So when it is an ‘F’ its will have a future date in date due So I am using a `CASE WHEN State = 'F' THEN DateDue WHEN State = 'R' THEN DateComplete END AS Date` statement (forgive me if syntax is out its just an example).
What I am trying to achieve is a running total by month of open accounts. I’ve found guides on cumulative counts by month but cant find one by month for running total. The end output I need is (not based on above figures)

```
Month   OpenAccounts
Jan-14  1
Feb-14  3
Mar-14  2
Apr-14  5
```

Will happily answer any questions If I haven’t been clear. (I have had to repost this question after deleting the original).

Answer (score 0):

```
;with CTE as -- Get all dates with month year combo
( select CASE [STATE] WHEN 'F' THEN DateDue 
                      WHEN 'R' THEN DateComplete END AS TransDate         
 from  @Account
 where Status = 'OPEN'  
 )  
select  DATENAME(mm,T1.TransDate) +'-'+
        CAST (YEAR(T1.TransDate) AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Month,
        count(distinct T2.TransDate) as runsum
from CTE as T2
cross join CTE T1  
where 1= case when  DATENAME(mm,T1.TransDate) +'-'+ 
                    CAST (YEAR(T1.TransDate) AS VARCHAR(20)) =
                    DATENAME(mm,T2.TransDate) +'-'+ 
                    CAST (YEAR(T2.TransDate) AS VARCHAR(20)) 
                    and  T2.TransDate <  T1.TransDate  then 1
              when T2.TransDate <=  T1.TransDate then 1
         end
group by DATENAME(mm,T1.TransDate) +'-'+ 
         CAST (YEAR(T1.TransDate) AS VARCHAR(20))
order by runsum asc
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/IEEJ40400)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I cant seem to get this to work with my data as it doesnt appear to match the data I am using?

Comment: In your CTE your initial select query is only referencing open accounts. meaning that you are ignoring closed accounts. There is no way to identify when an account is closed? I need to know how many accounts are open each month. Not a cumulative total. If there are 2 accounts in Jan, then another 4 open in feb then that would give 6. But if 3 accounts closed in feb it would reduce the figure by those 3..

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
  (
     mon          INT,
     yr           INT,
     cnt          INT,
     runningtotal INT
  )
DECLARE @runningtotal INT 

INSERT INTO @table
            (mon,
             yr,
             cnt)
SELECT Datepart(MONTH, yourcolumn) AS mon,
       Datepart(YEAR, yourcolumn)  AS yr,
       Count(*)                    cnt
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY Datepart(MONTH, yourcolumn),Datepart(YEAR, yourcolumn)

UPDATE @table
SET    @runningtotal = @runningtotal + cnt,
       runningtotal = @runningtotal

SELECT mon,
       yr,
       runningtotal
FROM   @table
```